# when i create and construct 2 objects of the same type, they copy each other to the last constructed object

Tags: c#

im a noob in c#. My problem comes when i want to create 2 objects

```
two_digt d1,d2;
```

of course i got to call for two_digt(int n) to create an object. But when i do it for d1 and d2, the last one called overwrites the first. Let me introduce to you my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class two_digt {
            private static int dgt1, dgt2;
            public two_digt(int n) {//constructor
                dgt1 = n % 10;
                dgt2 = (n % 100)/10;
            }
            public void print() {//funct to show what they've got
                Console.WriteLine("dgt1:"+ dgt1 );
                Console.WriteLine("dgt2:"+ dgt2 );
            }
        }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            two_digt d1 = new two_digt(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            d1.print();
            two_digt d2 = new two_digt(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            //printing each objects
            d2.print();
            d1.print();

            Console.ReadLine();//just to keep console from closing
        }
    }
}
```

Now i will show you the program i/o:

input:

```
1234
8765
//as you can suggest from my code "two_digt" will took for the 
//first 2 digits of both numbers
```

output:

```
//d1.print();
dgt1:4
dgt2:3
//d2.print();
dgt1:6
dgt2:5
//d1.print();
dgt1:6
dgt2:5
//What...?
```

that is actually my issue and i dont understand what .net framework does with data structures, please leave an answer to this ,or, if you can, leave a pro explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that dgt1, dgt2 are static. Remove the static modifier and you should get separate values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class two_digt
    {
        private int dgt1, dgt2;
        public two_digt(int n)
        {//constructor
            dgt1 = n % 10;
            dgt2 = (n % 100) / 10;
        }
        public void print()
        {//funct to show what they've got
            Console.WriteLine("dgt1:" + dgt1);
            Console.WriteLine("dgt2:" + dgt2);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            two_digt d1 = new two_digt(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            d1.print();
            two_digt d2 = new two_digt(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            //printing each objects
            d2.print();
            d1.print();

            Console.ReadLine();//just to keep console from closing
        }
    }
}
```